# Odata filter for "does not contain" operator

Tags: c#, odata

I have tried finding but I am unable to figure out what the equivalent OData filter string would be for the "Does not contain" operator. This is what I did for the "Contains" operator:

```
case FilterOperator.Contains:
                    odataFilter = $"contains({queryFilter.FieldName}, '{value}')";
                    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

`odataFilter = $"indexof({queryFilter.FieldName}, '{value}') eq -1";`

This will returns entities where the value in `FieldName` does not contain `value`.

The `indexof` function will return -1 if the specified string in the second parameter could not be found in the field specified in the first parameter.

See the reference to the technical documentation for more information:
https://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/odata-v4.0-part2-url-conventions.html#_Toc371341777